# Maven: How to clean integration-test configurations

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, lifecycle

In our maven project, we have integration test that sets all sorts of things on the integration test server.

I want to be be able to easily clean this things in a command. I want to be able to run:

```
mvn integration-clean
```

And this will clean all the things on the server, by running some cleaning mojos from my maven plugin.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

These are the commands in order to perform a complete `integration test`:

Step 1: `mvn deploy`

Step 2: `mvn integration-test`

Finally do a complete clean install in order to update the changes.

Step 3: `mvn clean install`

You could refer [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for the exact life cycle of the build.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having the integration profile defined in settings.xml.

```
<settings>
  ...
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>integrationProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  ...
</settings>
```

Assuming the integration profile is active ,

```
mvn clean install -P integrationProfile
```

should work for you.